# Bad ssh key file can't be removed because part of missing user profile

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

An ssh key from a profile path that no longer exists is stuck in my ssh agent config.

Now every time I boot my SSH agent I get `/Users/missinguserprofile/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory`

If I try `ssh-add -d /Users/missinguserprofile/.ssh/id_rsa` I get the error:

```
 Bad key file /Users/missinguserprofile/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
```

How do I remove this key?

Comment: Where do you add it? `.bashrc`? I assume you created this key and told `ssh-agent` to load it - so you should know where it's being added

Comment: Ditto. Check the config of the SSH agent.

Comment: I checked the ssh-agent `~/.ssh/config` file and it isn't in there which is where I would have expected it to be along with the other entries I can see it referencing in there. I'm using ZSH and it isn't in `.zshrc`.